# How to connect washing machine waste to a rubber hose within a stand pipe?

Tags: washing-machine

How to connect washing machine waste to a rubber hose within a stand pipe? I just moved in to an older rental unit. Pic below
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot just stick it in there?

Comment: Can you unscrew the port and get better access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. That rubber hose tear very certainly looks like it was caused by the sharp point of the screw sticking through the metal bracket. Back the screw out until the tip is hidden so the tear doesn't get worse. Also, report this to your landlord so he knows that this is an existing issue that needs to be addressed, and not something you've caused.
2. You don't show us your washing machine hose, but I'm more than willing to be that you can simply push the hose down into that white rubber tube and that it'll stay there.

   - You want the end of the washing machine drain hose to go down past the cut in the white rubber to ensure that water doesn't escape through that, making a mess in the wall.
   - Here in the US, the drain tube is usually pretty thick, stiff rubber with the end of the hose bent into something of a hook shape. The end of the hose goes into the stand pipe and the hook holds it into place. There's no need to clamp, seal or otherwise - gravity ensure that the water going down continues to go down the drain. Additionally, the air gap ensures water doesn't siphon back into the washer, and it vents the drain pipe to ensure that the water doesn't back up.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I'm buying the washing machine later as I will notify the rental agent and landlord first about the tear. Cheers! This is Melbourne, Australia :)

Comment: the white stand pipe here looks like a pvc material.

Answer (score 2):

It’s important that the washer drain hose is NOT attached to the drain pipe. There must be air space between the washer hose and the drain pipe.
Some people will clamp or tape the drain hose directly to the drain pipe to prevent water from backing up in the drain pipe.
If the drain hose is  entirely enclosed to the drain pipe, the washer will siphon. This means that the washer will drain and fill at the same time, endlessly until you turn if off and the washer tub empties.
It’s also very important that the washer drain hose isn’t attached to another hose (like a garden hose or a swimming pool drain hose). Some people do this to run the used washer water out to the yard. This will also cause a siphon. The end of the drain hose MUST BE higher than the water level in the washer. So, you can not attach another hose and lay it on the ground.